# how to remove downvote / get rep back after a question is migrated?

Tags: support, reputation, migration

We had a [really poor question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10506/photo-editing-effect) show up on photo.SE recently that I downvoted. Shortly thereafter there was some conversation in the comments and it was decided that it wasn't a bad question so much as just asked in the wrong venue, so they decided to move it to another stack. After the migration however it's question vote was reset to 0, and I can't un-down-vote anymore. Anyway to recover that rep point? or is it gone for good? (note that a recalc didn't help it, and I'm nowhere near the rep cap.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't undo votes on migrated questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9414/cant-undo-votes-on-migrated-questions)

Answer (score 2):

You can recover that 1 back only after [the question on the original site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10506/photo-editing-effect?noredirect=1) get deleted, by recalculating your rep at https://photo.stackexchange.com/reputation